# How to seek negative off the current position in file?

Tags: ruby, file

I'm trying to seek 2 bytes backwards from current position in ruby. The following code tries to find previous end of line.

```
    1.9.3-p448 :003 > while file.getc != '\n'
    1.9.3-p448 :004?>   file.seek(-2,IO::SEEK_CUR)
    1.9.3-p448 :005?>   end
    Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - test
    from (irb):4:in `seek'
    from (irb):4
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I'm unable to understand why I'm getting this error. It seeks perfectly outside loop (the same statement).
test is the filename.

Comment: I'm curious why you're using `getc` to read from a text file? It'd be easier and a lot faster to read lines and keep a small buffer in memory of the last couple lines read, and move forward/backward through that buffer, than it would be to rely on `getc`, character matching on disk and file positioning. Your code sample has a very "C" like smell, which isn't how we'd usually do file I/O in Ruby, except for very specific (rare) cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that your problem is that you're not two bytes into the file yet. I just did this with a simple text file:

```
>> fp = File.new('pancakes.txt', 'r')
>> fp.readline
>> fp.seek(-2, IO::SEEK_CUR)
=> 0
>> fp.seek(-20, IO::SEEK_CUR)
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - x.txt
```

The first line of the file was only a couple characters long so `-20` would try to put me before the beginning of the file.

I think you just need to throw a [`pos`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-pos) check into the mix: if `file.pos == 0` then you're at the beginning and a negative seek will raise an exception.

Comment: What's in your file? What is `file.pos` when you start the loop?

Comment: this is the statement before the loop file.seek(-2,IO::SEEK_END)

Comment: so? why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know, what is `file.pos` right before the exception? How big is the file? Does it have any newlines at all?